# Powershell issue putting process name into hashtable if it's not found

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run on a list of processes and if found put the process name in hashtable with value True and if not False, the True part works just fine I got an issue if the process is not found it won't pair the searched process name with Flase just be blank

**CODE**

```
$processStatus = $null

$processStatus = @{}

$processName = "firefox", "discord", "fgdfg"
[System.Diagnostics.Process[]]$processList = Get-Process $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
 Sort-Object -Property name -Unique

ForEach ($process in $processList) {
    if($process -ne $null) {
        $processStatus.Add($process.ProcessName,"True")
    } else {
        $processStatus.Add($process,"Flase")
      }
}
```

**Result**

```
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
Discord                        True                                            
firefox                        True
```

**Expected result**

```
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
Discord                        True                                            
firefox                        True
fgdfg                          False
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is the best way to do it, I just need a simple true/false checker for some processes and put the name/vaule into a hashtable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quite close. You just need loop through the process names and run [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7) against each process name. Then check if the process exists before setting the status in the hash table.

```
$processNames = "firefox", "discord", "fgdfg"

$processStatus = @{}
foreach ($processname in $processNames) {
    $processes = Get-Process -Name $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($null -ne $processes) {
        $processStatus[$processName] = $true
    }
    else {
        $processStatus[$processName] = $false
    }
}
```

<sup>Also make sure to put `$null` on the left side of the operator when doing comparisons. If your using VSCode, `PSScriptAnalyzer` will give a `PSPossibleIncorrectComparisonWithNull` warning if you don't do this. Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/PossibleIncorrectComparisonWithNull.md) for more information as to *why* this is recommended.</sup>

We could also use the .NET method [`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netcore-3.1) to get the processes that share the same name. This method returns `System.Diagnostics.Process[]`, so we can simply check if the count is greater than 0.

```
$processNames = "firefox", "discord", "fgdfg", "notepad"

$processStatus = @{}
foreach ($processname in $processNames) {
    $processes = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessesByName($processName)

    if ($processes.Count -gt 0) {
        $processStatus[$processName] = $true
    }
    else {
        $processStatus[$processName] = $false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute `Get-Process` against each individual process name instead:

```
$processStatus = @{}
$processName = "firefox", "discord", "fgdfg"

$processName |ForEach-Object {
  $processStatus[$_] = @(Get-Process -Name $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count -gt 0
}
```

If you want a list of status objects instead, you could also use `Select-Object`:

```bsh
$processNames |Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_}},@{Name='Status';Expression={@(Get-Process -Name $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count -gt 0}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I went with the other solution